# How to map value to manually added columns in sharepoint designer using XSLT code

Tags: asp.net, xslt, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I have two columns: **Month** and **No** which are retrieved from SharePoint list. As I added data into SharePoint designer the below code is automatically generated in code panel. I had changed a few lines of code, however it didn't work correctly. I would be grateful if anybody assist to achieve this.

```
    Input Data:(Data retrieved from List)
        Month    No
        Jan-18   1
        Feb-18   1      
        Feb-18   1
        Apr-18   1
        Apr-18   1
        May-18   1
        May-18   1
        Jun-18   1

Code:
<td class="ms-vb" style="width: 373px">
                <xsl:value-of select="@Month" />
            </td>       

 <xsl:if test="string(@Month)='Jan 18'">
                    <td class="ms-vb">

                        <xsl:value-of select="@No_x0020__x0027_of_x0020_Instanc" /> </td> </xsl:if>
```

Here columns are added manually and values should map accordingly

```
Output:
           Jan-18  Feb-18 Apr-18  May-18 Jun-18
             1       2      2      2      1
```

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient way would be to define two keys:

- on Month
- on both Month and No

You can use ***for-each*** which will simplify the count expression :

```
 <xsl:key name="monthKey" match="/items/Item" use="@Month"/>
 <xsl:key name="noKey" match="/items/Item" use="concat(@Month, '|', @No)"/>

<xsl:for-each select="/items/Item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('monthKey',@Month)[1])]">
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-vb" style="width: 373px">
                <xsl:value-of select="@Month" />
            </td>
            <td class="ms-vb">
                <xsl:for-each select="key('monthKey',@Month)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('noKey', concat(@Month, '|', @No))[1])]">
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(key('noKey', concat(@Month, '|', @No)))"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

I have made sample XML from your data as following,
U can change you XPATH accordingly.

```
<items>
<Item Month='Jan-18' No='1'/>
<Item Month='Feb-18' No='1'/>
<Item Month='Feb-18' No='1'/>
<Item Month='Apr-18' No='1'/>
<Item Month='Apr-18' No='1'/>
<Item Month='May-18' No='1'/>
<Item Month='May-18' No='1'/>
<Item Month='Jun-18' No='1'/>
</items>
```